# trying to pull map from arcgis server

Tags: arcgis

I am trying to fetch and display a map from the arcgis server using Aptana IDE. It says l is undefined.

> GET https://gistest2.xxx.xxx/arcgis/rest/info?f=json
>
> 200 OK        27ms TypeError: l is undefined
>
> ...x)<=p.dx)&&q._addFrameInfo(h,p);this.setExclusionAreas(this.exclusionAreas);this...

Here is the entire code except the URL I am trying to hit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

        <!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples

        on iOS devices-->

        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">

        <title>BGSU Memorial Trees Location</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/js/esri/css/esri.css">

        <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/">

        </script>

        <script>

        var map;

    require(["esri/map", "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer", "dojo/domReady!"],

    function (Map, ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer ) {

    map = new Map("map", {               

        center: [-76.756, 40.241],

        zoom: 8

    });           

    var customBasemap = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(

    "https://XXX/");



    map.addLayer(customBasemap);

});

        </script>

    </head>

    <body class="claro">

                     <div align="center"><strong>BGSU Memorial Trees Listing   </strong><hr>

<i><a target="_self" href="listingtrees.html">Listing</a> | <a target="_self" href="locationtrees.html">Locations </a></i>

</div>

<br>

        <div id="map" >

        </div>



    </body>

</html>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer you have to specify the URL of an ArcGIS tiled map service. Example of URL:

```
  http://myserver/arcgis/rest/services/map_service_name/MapServer
```

The address you specified (arcgis/rest/info?f=json) is the address of the REST service of ArcGIS Server but doesn't point to a Map service.

Comment: Hello, I gave the Mapserver url in ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer. It didn't work. It throws me these two errors 

GET https://gistest2.bgsu.edu/arcgis/rest/info?f=json
 
200 OK
  41ms 
/3.10/ (line 159)
TypeError: h is undefined
 

...(s.scale=96*s.scale/a.dpi),l=m(a,k,s),s.startTileRow=0>l.row?0:l.row,s.startTile...
Not sure why. Please look into this, let me know if I am doing something wrong. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I get these two new errors when I tried pull the map not sure why.
GET https://gistest2.bgsu.edu/arcgis/rest/info?f=json
 
200 OK
  77ms 
/3.10/ (line 159)
TypeError: h is undefined
 

...(s.scale=96*s.scale/a.dpi),l=m(a,k,s),s.startTileRow=0>l.row?0:l.row,s.startTile...

/3.10/ (line 205)
TypeError: this.spatialReference is undefined
 

...n c},_getFrameWidth:function(){var a=-1,b=this.spatialReference._getInfo();this.... Please let me if making anything wrong.

Comment: I've tried your code with a sample map server (http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer) and it works. So it must be either the map service you use or another problem. From the error it seems that it's not loading the ESRI JS framework. Check the console of the browser to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Hello, THank you for trying it. The errors I have posted above are from my console. It says H is undefined and when I don't have h in my program. One more error is weird, sometimes it shows spatial reference error, sometimes it doesn't.